# GoogleMap- Black screen when transiting

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I am using `GoogleMap` along with `SherlockMapFragment`. After opening up the Google Map (full screen), I clicked on the phone's hardware Back menu. I realized there is a noticeable (1-2 secs) black screen as it transit to the previous fragment.

Though the screen is black, the zoom levels (i.e + and - signs) can still be seen.

Could you please explain how should I go about to prevent such black screens?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I suggest posting some code showing how exactly do you setup your `Activity`/`Fragment`. without this it's just guessing.